# Codeception: DB is not rolling back in API testing

Tags: laravel, codeception

I am testing some certain parts of my API and have noticed that a specific table the DB is not rolling back when my test fail.

Here is my `api.suite.yml` file:

```
class_name: ApiTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - REST:
            depends: Laravel5
        - \Helper\Api
        - Db
```

And this is my code in codeception.yml:

```
actor: Tester
paths:
    tests: tests
    log: tests/_output
    data: tests/_data
    support: tests/_support
    envs: tests/_envs
settings:
    bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
    colors: true
    memory_limit: 1024M
extensions:
    enabled:
        - Codeception\Extension\RunFailed
modules:
    config:
        Db:
            dsn: 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test_records'
            user: 'root'
            password: ''
            dump: 'tests/_data/dump.sql'
            populate: true
            cleanup: true
            reconnect: true
```

Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Db module does not rollback, it loads dump before each test.

Comment: Laravel5 module uses transaction and rolls back by default. So using these 2 modules together can cause some interesting issues. It would probably be better to disable Laravel5 rollback be setting `cleanup: false` under it, or stop using Db module and use ORM features of Laravel5 module for database manipulation and assertions.

Comment: Sure, I will get try removing the Laravel5 module and see how it goes.
Will update this thread.